# What is Synthesizer and Sequencer(javax.sound.midi) in Java?

Tags: java, audio, midi, sound-synthesis, javax.sound.midi

I want to know the Actual Work of Synthesizer and Sequencer or what did they acually do?

Comment: This question is way too broad. See the package documentation, and Wikipedia ([MIDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDI), [Synthesizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthesizer)). Please ask a more specific question.

Comment: Atleast tell the difference between Synthesizer and Sequencer. @CL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A synthesizer is a component that converts MIDI messages into actual sounds.

A sequencer handles the timing of MIDI messages, i.e., it allows to record MIDI messages together with their time stamps, and allows to later play them back (i.e., to send them to some other device) with the same timing.